# creating a pre-defined set for reg-exp. (gsub, grepl,...)

Tags: regex, r, gsub, grepl

Hi I am trying to create a special string just like `digit` in grepl (`R`).

`string <- c("a>-787", "ahigji<=!5")`

Say,

```
 special_characters <- c(">-!", "<=!")
```

Now I am trying to see if there are entries in the string with `special characters`.

```
  grepl("special_characters", string)
```

Also I have tried   `grepl("[special_characters]", string) , grepl("[[:special_characters:]]", string)`

But it gives me an irrelevant answer ! on testing for different strings.

I just wanna use something like `[[:digit]]`- In short I need to create a predefined set and I need to use it in `grepl or gsub`

Comment: You could use it like this, but I m not sure if it would be acceptable: `special_characters <- paste(">-!", "<=!", sep='|'); grepl(special_characters, string) `

Comment: @LyzandeR cool :) Guess it works but will give a best thorough testing. Thanx  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
special_characters <- c(">-!", "<=!")
spchars <- paste(special_characters, collapse='|')
grepl(spchars, string)
```

It works by using `|`, aka "or" to check for any of the strings you put in `special_characters`. They can even be regexps!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you will *not* be able to create equivalents of `[:digit:]`, `[:space:]`, `[:alnum:]`, `[:punct:]`, etc... because these are built in to the internal regex engine; they are not specific to functions like `grepl` or `regexp`, nor are they something controlled by R.

However, doing something like this will get you essentially the same behavior:

```
special_chars <- "[>\\-\\!<\\=]"
string <- c("a>-787", "ahigji<=!5")
##
R> grepl(special_chars, string)
#[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: I believe I need the output as logical. In the sense just binary not a logical vector of length > 1

Comment: As in `any(grepl(special_chars, string))` or `all(grepl(special_chars, string))` (depending on what you are checking for)?